# Fickering screen after installing ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, 17.10, intel

I have the following problem. Just installed Ubuntu 17.10 but i get a flickering display.

Below i have run this output
lspci -nnk|grep -iA2 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
How and where can i get the correct one?

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the power system. when i plug in the power adapter the flickering stops.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but https://askubuntu.com/a/1043655/114641