# Graphics problem on Ubuntu 18.04 - blurred text + screen flickering

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, 18.04, intel, visual-artifacts

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 a day ago. It works perfectly but graphics is a problem; I see screen flickering where there are system or JS overlays and blurred text.

What can I do - my graphics are based on intel chip

Running sudo lshw -c display

I get

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 520
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:127 memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Check the [terminal output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uONv3.png)

Comment: I think you'll need to give some more detailed hardware information here. Graphics devices should come up when you run `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` or `sudo lshw -c display`. Can you [edit] your question to add that info?

Comment: Thanks @Zanna , I have edited the question to include the extra details

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the flicker, I had to REMOVE these two lines from `/etc/environment` (you probably don't have them, unless you installed `gnome-wobbly-windows` extension)

```
CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling
CLUTTER_VBLANK=True
```

And I also had to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and then reboot

For nVidia cards:
To make the text non-blurry, I just increased the screen resolution via `nvidia-settings` (the Display dialog did not let me change the resolution)

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan.  This worked on my Dell Precision 5510. Symptoms only appeared in Gnome desktop, not XFCE. I had tough time until I found this info.