# Ubuntu 18.04 screen strobing

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, flicker

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, and I am experiencing subtle (but constant and rather annoying) screen flicker. My computer is an HP Envy x360 Convertible 15-bp1xx; using Intel graphics driver. The flickering is not specific to any application, but it is more visible in large medium-gray areas (e.g. applications with dark themes, desktop backgrounds, etc.)

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Probably not your issue, but I fixed it with: https://askubuntu.com/a/1043655/114641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue.  Was fixed by changing the refresh rate to 59.96 or 59.93 (it was on 60.01) - no clue why.  Just opened display settings and fiddled around after reading much older posts on similar issues.

Hope this sorts it out for you!

Answer (score 2):

I had to edit my monitor config and change the framerate. By default mine was set to 60.169086456298828.

open terminal and run the following:

```
sudo gedit ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

edit this line:

```
<rate>60.169086456298828</rate>
```

set it to be lower than 60 as mentioned by 4levels, I used 59.96.